# Zend Framework Pagination - Use of Next / Prev / First / Last instead of page numbers in Controller Action

Tags: php, zend-framework, pagination

**Scenario**

I have an application that gets data from a web page and want to fetch records one at a time and want to achieve pagination without page numbers (if feasible).

**Details**

*In Zend Framework, I want to construct the appropriate routes for a paged application that will rely upon next, prev, first, last buttons instead of absolute page numbers.*

*Note: For sake of clarity I have provided some details into my project route below.*

**Route Requirements**

Instead of:
**ActionItemDashboard/ActionItemDetail/page/1**

I want to use
**ActionItemDashboard/ActionItemDetail/first**

**Question**

If I am not going overboard with my request and if it is simple, what general approach in Zend Framework, or any MVC structured app, do I need to take to address records by next previous first last instead of page numbers?

If this is overboard, what is the simplest way to get pagination without page numbers?